# How to get button input to display on textarea

Tags: javascript

```
<body>
<center>
<h1>Online Calculator</h1>
<hr/>
<form name="frmCalculator" action="">
    <table border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" width="30%">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4"><textarea style="width:100%" name="txtResult"></textarea></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4"><input type="reset" style="width:100%"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="button" value="      7      " onclick="7"/></td>
            <td><input type="button" value="      8      " onclick="8"/></td>
            <td><input type="button" value="      9      " onclick="9"/></td>
            <td><input type="button" value="     +      " onclick="plus()"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="button" value="      4      " onclick="4"/></td>
            <td><input type="button" value="      5      " onclick="5"/></td>
            <td><input type="button" value="      6      " onclick="6"/></td>
            <td><input type="button" value="      -      " onclick="subtract()"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="button" value="      1      " onclick="1"/></td>
            <td><input type="button" value="      2      " onclick="2"/></td>
            <td><input type="button" value="      3      " onclick="3"/></td>
            <td><input type="button" value="      *      " onclick="times()"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="button" value="      0      " onclick="0"/></td>
            <td><input type="button" value="      .       " onclick="."/></td>
            <td><input type="button" value="      =      " onclick="total()"/></td>
            <td><input type="button" value="      /      " onclick="divide()"/></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
</center>
</body>
```

I'm making a calculator. How do I make the input from the button display on the textarea? I have to make the numbers display on the text area like a normal calculator. I can't use jquery because we haven't learned it yet.

Comment: Add a listener that reads the value and writes it to the textarea. What have you tried so far? Something like `this.form.txtResult.value = this.value` might get you started.

Comment: I've tried using the onclick event to write to the textarea. I assumed if I assigned onclick="4" it would work.

Comment: The value of the *onclick* attribute is interpreted as javascript. "4" is just a number, it doesn't do anything. Replace it with the code in the previous comment.

Comment: Instead of `onclick="5"` or `onclick="6"`  etc, you can do something like `onclick="displayNumber(5)"` or `onclick="displayNumber(6)"` etc... Where displayNumber is a function that receives a number and change the value of the textarea ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add the numbers to the textarea you can use this code:

```
var button = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=button]');

for(var x=0; x<button.length; x++)
{
    button[x].addEventListener('click', function(e) {

     var a = document.getElementById('txt').value;

     document.getElementById('txt').value = a + this.value;


    });

}
```

If you want a list of all elements that match a selector, you can use [document.querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll) and loop through the object list.

You will need to alter your html and delete all the wrong onclicks, you too should use the value attribute only for the actual value and not for code styling, as the output will include your spaces, too.

```
<center>
<h1>Online Calculator</h1>
<hr/>
<form name="frmCalculator" action="">
    <table border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" width="30%">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4"><textarea style="width:100%" id="txt" name="txtResult"></textarea></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4"><input type="reset" style="width:100%"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="button" value="7"/></td>
            <td><input type="button" value="8"/></td>
            <td><input type="button" value="9"/></td>
            <td><input type="button" value="+" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="button" value="4" /></td>
            <td><input type="button" value="5" /></td>
            <td><input type="button" value="6" /></td>
            <td><input type="button" value="-" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="button" value="1" /></td>
            <td><input type="button" value="2"/></td>
            <td><input type="button" value="3" /></td>
            <td><input type="button" value="*" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="button" value="0" /></td>
            <td><input type="button" value="." /></td>
            <td><input type="button" value="="/></td>
            <td><input type="button" value="/" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
</center>
```

I didn't implement the calculating functions, but I hope this is enough for you to start with.

Comment: Note that in `a + parseInt(this.value)` the use of *parseInt* is pointless. `this.value` is a string to start with, so is *a*, so the `+` operator will convert the result of `parseInt(this.value)` back to a string then append it to the value of *a* as if *parseInt* had not been used.

Comment: @RobG actually it had to be used, I've been wondering too. OP has many spaces in the value data, which get printed without the use of parseInt

Comment: That's because the OP is using the value to set the size of the button. The value should be set to the required value and styling used to set the size of the button.

Comment: That's true, I'll mention this in my answer @RobG

Answer (score 0):

Simplistically, you can do:

```
<input type="button" value="7" onclick="this.form.txtResult.value = this.value">
```

However, you may want to add a listener to each button that is a number that does the same thing. The easiest way to do that is to add a class to the number buttons and give them all the same listener, so:

```
<input type="button" value="7" class="numberButton">
```

and use the load event to add the listeners:

```
window.onload = function() {
  var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.numberButton');
  for (var i=0, iLen=buttons.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    buttons[i].onclick = function(){
      this.form.txtResult.value += this.value;
    };
  }
};
```

You can also add specific listeners for the other buttons.

PS. To get the buttons all the same size, use styles to set the width the same, don't use the value.